# docker mysql-server not starting on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, docker, vagrant

I'm trying to start the a mysql docker container inside an ubuntu trusty Vagrant VM:

```
docker run --name my-container-name -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql/mysql-server:5.6
```

The container starts and stops after about 12 seconds.

Looking at the log I can see the following:

```
...
Finished mysql_install_db
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
/entrypoint.sh: line 31:    58 Killed                  mysqld --user=mysql --datadir="$DATADIR" --skip-networking
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process failed.
```

Any idea why the mysqld process is killed?
The vagrant VM has the newest docker (1.8.2) installed.

Running the same command on my windows machine (boot2docker) works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Okay - don't know what exactly happens but it seems to be related to the actual vagrant box. Doesn't work on "ubuntu/trusty64". With "puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64" mysql starts as expected.

Comment: Check if they are using different storage drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in the logs for any errors with

```
docker ps -a
docker logs {mysql sha}
```

You should be able to see what error mysql shows.

How does your script look that runs the command?

Comment: The logs above is already the output of docker logs {mqsql sha}.
I don't use a special script, just the above command line. The default Dockerfile uses an entrypoint.sh as startup script, which is also used.